# Does Cauchy criterion (for series) imply that $\sum _{k=n } ^{m }c _k \le \epsilon $?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does Cauchy criterion (for series) imply that $\sum _{k=n } ^{m }c _k \le \epsilon $?

In theorem 3.25 in Rudins principles it is stated that under the assumption that  $\sum _{k=n } ^{\infty}c _k $ is convergent, given $\epsilon >0 $, there exists $N \ge  N _0 $, such that for all $m, n \ge N $
$$
\sum _{k=n } ^{m }c _k \le \epsilon 
$$

Now Cauchy Criterion imply $ |\sum _{k=n } ^{m }c _k | \le \epsilon $.
Does the above follows from this. Or have I missed something other essential?

(Also when I'm at it: Why does Rudin state the Cauchy condition for sequences as $ \forall \epsilon, \ \exists N : \ d(p _n, p _m ) < \epsilon $, for $n,m \ge N $, but when treating the partial sums as a sequence the criterion is stated as $ |\sum _{k=n } ^{m }c _k | \le \epsilon $ with $\ge $ instead of >.)

Answer (score 1):

If you have $$\left|\sum_{k=n}^m c_k\right| \leq \epsilon,$$
then if the sum is positive, $$\sum_{k=n}^m c_k=\left|\sum_{k=n}^m c_k\right|\leq \epsilon.$$
If the sum is negative, then of course it is also smaller than $\epsilon$, as $\epsilon>0$.

Also, in all $\epsilon$-definitions, is is equivalent to demand $\leq$ and $<$

Comment: Why is it equivalent to demand $\le $ or < ?

Comment: Because $\varepsilon>0$ is arbitrary.

Comment: Because if something is $\leq \epsilon$ for any $\epsilon$, it is also $\leq \epsilon/2$ for any $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

The idea here is that if the sequence $(a_{k})$ is Cauchy, then given $c_{k}=a_{k}-a_{k-1}$(I assume this is what you mean) implies that for all $\epsilon$ there exists $N$ such that for all $m,n\geq N$, $|a_{m}-a_{n}|\leq \epsilon$ which clearly implies that $|c_{n}|\leq \epsilon$. Therefore, if you fix $\epsilon$ you can take $N$ large enough, such that for all $l\in \mathbb{N}$ and all $m,n\geq N$ with $m-n=l$, we obtain that $max_{n\leq k\leq m}\{|c_{k}|\}\leq \frac{\epsilon}{l}$. This comes from the fact that the sequence is Cauchy. But, this then implies that $\sum_{k=n}^{m} |c_{k}|\leq \sum_{k=n}^{m} \frac{\epsilon}{l}=\epsilon$.

The last step is to use the fact that $|\sum c_{k}|\leq \sum|c_{k}|$ for any sequence ($c_{k})$. Hope this is clear.